# R: Execute commands at exact time after program start

Tags: r, time

I am maybe misusing R a little, but I wish to execute R commands et specific times after my script started. The time when the commands should be executed is saved in a data frame.

e.g.

```
Time <- c(0.5, 5, 13, 30)
Text <- c("Half a second", "5 seconds", "13 seconds", "Half a minute")

df <- data.frame(Time = Time, Text = Text) 
df
#  Time          Text
#1  0.5 Half a second
#2  5.0     5 seconds
#3 13.0     13 seconds
#4 30.0 Half a minute
```

The aim is to execute a command eg. `print()` after x Millisecond (stored in `df$Time_ms`) since the program start has past.

My first approach would be just to use `Sys.sleep()` between the commands. This would be almost acceptable, but since each command also takes some time (`print()` not really but others more) it will not be super accurate.

My best solution is to use 'while' loops:

```
# Programm start
start_time <- Sys.time() # Save Program start time. 

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  while(Sys.time() < df$Time[i] + start_time){} # Wait until the System Time is larger than start time plus the time when the command shall be executed.  

  print(paste(df$Text[i], "has passed.")) # Execute the command. 
}
```

It is working. But I am not that experienced with programming, but I guess it is not a very elegant solution. What do you think? Does someone have a "nicer" solution?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/vignettes/taskscheduleR.html

Comment: Why you just don't use `Sys.sleep` instead of the `while` loop? For instance: `Sys.sleep(df$Time[i]-(as.numeric(Sys.time()-start_time)))`.

Comment: @mt1022 no, in general the time of the commands is way shorter, than the wating time in between but still not zero and will add up to an error. So the solution from nicols sound feasible for me.

Comment: OK. If the waiting time is short, that is a more accurate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the proposal from nicola, with a minor change. If the program runs already for more than a minute and you subtract the 'start_time' current time 'Sys.time()' the result will be in minutes and not in second anymore. To prevent this, I use 'difftime'.

```
# Create example data.frame
Time <- c(0.5, 5, 13, 30)
Text <- c("Half a second", "5 seconds", "13 seconds", "Half a minute")

df <- data.frame(Time = Time, Text = Text) 

# Programm start
start_time <- Sys.time() # Save Program start time. 

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  wait <- df$Time[i]-(as.numeric(difftime(Sys.time(),start_time, units = "secs"))) # Calculate the waiting time in second.

                    Sys.sleep(wait)
                    print(paste(df$Text[i], "has passed.")) # Execute the command. 
}
```